ctrl+] (or [ ) in VS Code indents lines using different tab size than default setting
Current settings:
tabSize = 2
autoIndent: advanced
indentSize: tabSize
insertSpaces: false
detectIndentation: false

When I use tab or shift+tab, my lines are indented/unindented according to the desired tab size, but when I use ctrl + ] (or [ ) then my lines are indented/unindented by 3 instead of 2, seen in screenshot
For what it's worth, this is observed in .rmd files
ctrl+ indents by 3 spaces, not tabsize of 2
I tried various different settings and editing JSON settings.
I expected the shortcut to indent according to set tabsize (of 2).
What happened was the shortcut indents by (seemingly) 3 spaces
